# How to integrate the unity ios project into native ios swift project?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, swift4

I've tried most of the online resources including this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075940/how-to-integrate-unity-into-a-swift-3-ios-project) too to integrate my unity project into **swift 4** native project but unfortunately not helped until now. When I do [Linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075940/how-to-integrate-unity-into-a-swift-3-ios-project) fix I got into below **c++** file error:

```
No member named 'GetHostByAddr40' in 'il2cpp::icalls::System::System::Net::Dns'; did you mean 'GetHostByAddr'?
```

Btw I am actually doing a **augmented reality** project which having some native iOS designs too. Since so I've done those parts using **swift 4** with **Xcode 9.2**. The native part contains the project's start and the end part. In between that, there is **augmented reality** part which is done by using **unity 2018.2.0f2 personal** and **vofuria 7.2.23**.

In the end, now I have an iOS native project and unity project. I wanted to integrate the unity part into iOS native!

Comment: try this out...https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity. I just found this and your post during a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I get ride the error.
After fixing with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075940/how-to-integrate-unity-into-a-swift-3-ios-project) described solutions, I've ended up with `Bulk_Mono.Security_1.cpp` file not found. So I've started to search for it. Then I've got identified the problem. The problem is with **4.0 Scripting runtime version** of .Net.  I made the project with 4.0 because of the use of **LitJson** requires min 4.0. The 4.0 is not generating the `Bulk_Mono.Security_1.cpp` file for iOS. Then I've removed the **LitJson** from the project and downgraded the project runtime version to 3.x Equivalent and it started to work fine with the changes on the following 2 files.

Note that just integrate the generated `objective-c` project as like a framework usually then make following changes and run.

1. made the change following on `DisplayManager.mm` generated file which is located in `classes/unity`. The auto-generated not contains the last line of `return deviceUnknown;`. So we have to write manually.

   ```
   elif PLATFORM_TVOS
        if (!strncmp(model, "AppleTV5,", 9))
      return deviceAppleTV1Gen;
    else if (!strncmp(model, "AppleTV6,", 9))
      return deviceAppleTV2Gen;
    else
       return deviceUnknown;
   endif
     return deviceUnknown
   ```
2. Do the following change on `SplashScreen.mm` which is located in generated project's `classes/ui`. Change the `bool hasStoryboard = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"LaunchScreen" ofType: @"storyboardc"] != nullptr;` to  `bool hasStoryboard = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"LaunchScreen_1" ofType: @"storyboardc"] != nullptr;`. The complete method below.

   ```
       void ShowSplashScreen(UIWindow* window)
       {
          bool hasStoryboard = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"LaunchScreen_1" ofType: @"storyboardc"] != nullptr;

          if (hasStoryboard)
          {
             UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: 
             @"LaunchScreen" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
             _controller = [storyboard 
             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"unitySplashStoryboard"];
           }
           else
              _controller = [[SplashScreenController alloc] init];

           [_controller create: window];
           [window makeKeyAndVisible];
       }
   ```

That's all about how I integrated.